# Dependent equality with 2 different type functions

Tags: coq, dependent-type

How do you work with dependent types where the function making the type differs?

I'm working on a problem where I have 2 dependent types where the
types are indexed in different ways.  I want to show a form
of proof irrelevance.  Basically, I want to prove

```
Theorem existT_eqrect_bool_irrel {A B} (P : A -> Type) p b (eq0 eq1 : b = true)
    (Q := fun (b : bool) => if b then P p else B) Qb :
    existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb true eq0) =
    existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb true eq1).
  destruct eq0.

Error: Abstracting over the terms "b0" and "eq0" leads to a term
fun (b1 : bool) (eq2 : b = b1) =>
forall eq3 : b = b1,
existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb b1 eq2) = existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb b1 eq3)
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "existT" of type
 "forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) (x : A), P x -> {x : A & P x}"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "A" : "Type"
 "P" : "A -> Type"
 "p" : "A"
 "eq_rect b Q Qb b1 eq2" : "Q b1"
The 4th term has type "Q b1" which should be coercible to 
"P p".
```

But, any attempts I make to change it are ill-typed in that
it no longer knows that `P p = Q true` because it generalizes the `true`
and `P p = Q b` isn't generally true.
If I try smaller cases, they follow immediately, e.g.

```
Theorem existT_eqrect_irrel {A} (P : A -> Type) a b (eq0 eq1 : a = b) Pa :
    existT P b (eq_rect a P Pa b eq0) =
    existT P b (eq_rect a P Pa b eq1).
  destruct eq0, eq1; apply eq_refl.
Qed.
```

Is it possible to prove `existT_eqrect_bool_irrel` without extra axioms?
Or, is there some similar form that is provable?
Additionally, working with types through `eq_rect` seems painful
in Coq.  Is there general advice to make it more manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, what you want is a consequence of proof irrelevance for equality. In general, this does not hold in Coq, ie. it is not provable that `forall (A : Type) (x y : A) (p q : x = y), p = q`. However, by [Hedberg's theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/coherence-theorem-for-martinlofs-type-theory/37DC581B6D915FE83B74AC5984899319), any type with decidable equality has proof irrelevant equality. A consequence of this is that your identity is provable, albeit not through a simple `destruct`:

```
From Coq Require Import Logic.Eqdep_dec.

Theorem existT_eqrect_bool_irrel {A B} (P : A -> Type) p b (eq0 eq1 : b = true)
    (Q := fun (b : bool) => if b then P p else B) Qb :
    existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb true eq0) =
    existT P p (eq_rect b Q Qb true eq1).
Proof.
  f_equal.
  destruct eq0 ; cbn.
  apply eq_rect_eq_dec.
  intros [] [].
  1,4: left ; easy.
  all: right ; congruence.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you!  This theorem works!  Using that bool equality is decidable seems to fix the whole thing.  I was trying existT because I saw a paper that recommended using it for dependent equalities.  I guess it's unnecessary here.

I was trying to use this as part of a bigger theorem.  Trying to apply the same proof there still lead to being ill-typed.  But, after proving this theorem, my theorem is a direct corollary, proven by just `apply existT_eqrect_bool_irrel`. So, everything works now.